# The radii of circles inscribed between a triangle incircle and its vertices

Tags: geometry

This follows directly from the question ["Relationship between circles touching incircle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/764339/409) posed by evil999man April 22, 2014, which, it seems to me, did not receive the answer he was seeking.  The challenge I set myself was:

> Consider the radii $a$, $b$, $c$, of the circles inscribed between the incircle of a triangle, radius $r$, and its vertices. Consider the claim that $a + b + c \geq r$.

The radii are readily expressed in terms of the angles of the triangle, but I've got bogged down in trigonometry.

Comment: Please add the link to the previous question

Comment: Here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/764339.

Answer (score 2):

Let

- $r$ be the inradius and $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_3$ be the radii of the $3$ circles.
- $\theta_k$ be the angle of triangle at the vertex containing circle with radius $\rho_k$.
- $\phi_k = \frac{\pi - \theta_k}{4}$ and $t_k = \tan\phi_k$.

It is not hard to work out:
$$\frac{\rho_k}{r} = \frac{1 - \sin\frac{\theta_k}{2}}{1 + \sin\frac{\theta_k}{2}} = \tan(\phi_k)^2 = t_k^2 $$

Notice
$$\sum_{k=1}^3\phi_k = \frac14\left(3\pi - \sum_{k=1}^3\theta_k\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
The addition formula of tangent for $3$ angles tell us
$$\frac{t_1 + t_2 + t_3 - t_1 t_2 t_3}{
1 - t_1 t_2 - t_2 t_3 - t_3 t_1} = \tan\left(\sum_{k=1}^3\phi_k\right) = \infty$$
This implies $t_1 t_2 + t_2 t_3 + t_3 t_1 = 1$. As a result,
$$\begin{align}\frac1r \sum_{k=1}^3\rho_k = \sum_{k=1}^3 t_k^2 
&= \frac12(t_1^2 + t_2^2) + \frac12(t_2^2 + t_3^2) + \frac12(t_3^2 + t_1^2)\\
&\ge t_1t_2 + t_2t_3 + t_3t_1 = 1\end{align}$$